# Debugger main loop

Tags: c++, windows, exception, debugging

I'm trying to implement in c++/Windows the "Debugger Main Loop"  described in this article: [Writing the Debugger's Main Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But I want any thrown exception to display an error message to the secreen and be caught by the debugger.
I understood that I can do this by giving `ContinueDebugEvent`  some value of DBG_??? but I don't know what it is.
What is this value?

I also noticed that console applications notify the debugger of exceptions when something is written to the console.
How can I filter actual exception from those things? Does it have anything to do with the "first chance" value?
thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your application IS the debugger, so you're the one who has to show an error message.

Comment: Let's put it this way: If the application I debug divides a number by 0, I want it to crash! :)

Comment: Pass DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED to ContinueDebugEvent; that tells the system to let the process continue its normal exception handling mechanism (e.g. your debugger has not handled the exception).  If it is a second-chance exception then the system will terminate the process.

Comment: ok, but then the process terminates even if its sends a notification because something was printed to the screen. IS tere a way to filter just the fatal exceptions?

Comment: Ugh.  Apparently the documentation is incorrect; you need to pass DBG_CONTINUE for OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT.  http://maximumcrack.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/outputdebugstring-awesomeness/

Answer (score 4):

The debugger receives an exception event for every exception that occurs in the debuggee.
If you pass `DBG_CONTINUE` to `ContinueDebugEvent`, the debugger swallows the exception and execution continues as if no exception happened in the first place. That means that the debuggee is not notified of it either.
If on the other hand you pass `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` the debuggee is notified and responsible for handling the exception.

Now, if the debuggee does **not** handle (read: catch) the exception, the debugger gets notified a second time, this time with `Event.u.Exception.dwFirstChance` set to 0. At this point the exception would terminate the process if you pass `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`.

Two things to keep in mind:

- The normal way to communicate a string to the debugger is `OutputDebugString`. No need to use self-defined exceptions unless you need to pass something other than a string.
- If you do plan on throwing your own exception to communicate certain events to the debugger, check the `Event.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode` and see if it matches your predefined exception type and use `DBG_CONTINUE` in that case.